# How to copy multiple files and move them to multiple folders using terminal for Mac

Tags: macos, bash, automator

I have a folder on my Mac's desktop called `Bthepics` that has 9 images that I want to copy and move to about 500 folders at once. These 500 folders are located in a folder on my Mac's desktop called `bigcities`. I don't want to have to do this manually by selecting all 9 images and dragging each group of nine to all 500 folders individually.

Can anybody show me how to do this using Mac's *Terminal* or *Automator* programs?

Comment: The folder `bigcities` contains only those 500 destination folders and nothing else? ... or is there a different way how to identify those 500 destination folders?

Comment: Hi @pabouk, the folder <code>bigcities</code> only contains the destination folders.

Answer (score 0):

This loops over every folder in `bigcities`, and copies all images from `Bthepics` to that folder.
Run this in Terminal, and see if it outputs what you want. You can simply copy-paste this block of code.

```
find ~/Desktop/bigcities -type d -maxdepth 1 -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' folder; do
  echo cp ~/Desktop/Bthepics/*.jpg "$folder"
done
```

To do the actual copying, remove the `echo` before pasting. I'm assuming that your source images have the extension `.jpg`.

Then just remove the original images manually.

Comment: Hi slhck! Thanks for the fast reply! I'm very new to coding, do I need to actually type in "find" and "done" in the code? Meaning can I just copy and paste the code you gave me as is into Terminal?

Comment: You just take the entire block of code and copy-paste it to the terminal. It should output 500 lines, something like `cp IMAGE_1.jpg IMAGE_2.jpg ... IMAGE_9.jpg /Users/matt/Desktop/bigcities/FOLDER_1/`, for you to inspect that it's doing the right thing. Once you're sure, you need to remove the `echo` and then paste it again, which will do the actual copying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler code which does not need to run external command (`find`) and pipe the output. The rest is the same as in the slhck's reply.

```
cd ~/Desktop/bigcities ; for folder in */ ; do
  echo cp ~/Desktop/Bthepics/*.jpg "$folder"
done
```

This code has one drawback: The list of the destination folders must not exceed about 260 000 characters (command line size limit on Mac OS X 10.5). For 500 folders it is about 500 characters per folder name.

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with xargs command for automation task like this:

```
find ~/Desktop/bigcities -type d -print0 | xargs -I% cp ~/Desktop/Bthepics/image[1-9].jpg %/
```

that was if your 9 images is named image1.jpg image2.jpg...
if your 9 images differ of names:

```
find ~/Desktop/bigcities -type d -print0 | xargs -I% cp ~/Desktop/Bthepics/file1.jpg ~/Desktop/Bthepics/file2.jpg ... ~/Desktop/Bthepics/file9.jpg %/
```

the command at the end of xargs is the same as you execute manually with % will be replaced by folders path

Btw, this command will copy images into the parent folder (~/Desktop/bigcities), so you need to remove it by 1 command:

```
rm ~/Desktop/bigcities/image[1-9].jpg
```

I hope you understand my idea and apply it for your case.